# SeemeCNC Rostock V2 in 2020

Tags: print-quality

Looking to get into 3D printing without spending too much up front for now. Found an assembled seemecnc Rostock V2 for sale at a very good price considering its MSRP is 1k for the kit pre-assembly.

My question is, will this 4 year old printer be significantly lacking in any way compared to a new lower-end printer from 2020? I know the technology moves so fast.

Thanks so much in advance,
Alex

Comment: I don't see where it's *lacking* compared to newer less expensive printers, but I wouldn't pay anywhere near the MSRP for it, as it doesn't look like it has any advantages over printers 1/5 its price.

Comment: I don't own a delta mechanical printer, but from what I've seen is that it can be more complicated than a Cartesian printer in troubleshooting. You should ask yourself if you have the skills (or want to develop the skills) to operate such a machine. Certainly if it is a printer assembled by someone else with unknown quirks?

Answer (score 1):

I definitely wouldn't start with a Delta printer.
Cartesian printers have become "the norm" for a good reason - they're very easy to use and tune, so I'd recommend getting an Ender 3 or Biqu B1.

It'll still print just fine, but that MSRP is in no way realistic in 2020. If it's offered under maybe 100$, it might be interesting as a secondary machine, but I wouldn't pay more than that.

Comment: In theory delta is awesome and can be extremely fast, but I think you need really precise & rigid mechanics plus really fine stepping (or gears) to get quality comparable to cartesian. With same steps/mm as what suffices on cartesian you'll get artifacts from the delta kinematics.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I agree - I got myself a cheap EZT T1 to get a hang of the kinematics, and it's pretty tricky to get them to work properly without a bed probe (which the Rostock does have though). The RAMBo in the Rostock seems to be AVR-based though, so I'd definitely expect better quality on a cartesian printer.